# Polite way to inform that there is no need to reply (business language)

Tags: formality, politeness, business-language, letter-writing

I am often requesting my colleges via email to update a status of a case they work on. The update (note) should be provided in application they work on which is also explained in my request. There is no need to reply to my email but many off them do. So I decided to add a note in my request:

"If you can proceed with ticket update, there is no need to reply to this email."

But it just doesn't sound right to me. Correct me if I am wrong. 
What is polite/bussines way to write that sentence ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it this way:

> "This is just a friendly reminder to update ticket. You need not reply to this email."

Answer (score 0):

You could be a bit friendlier with your guidelines. Maybe try

> Do not reply to this email unless you need assistance with the ticket update.

or

> Please reply to this email if you need assistance with the ticket update. Otherwise there is no need to reply.